# Error inserting data from SQL Server to AS400 using a linked server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ibm-midrange

I am trying to get data from my sql server data table to a file in the as400 using a IBMDASQL OLE DB Provider. If I try and run a straight insert statement it fails for:

INV801WK not journaled, no authority to the journal, or the journal state is *STANDBY.  Files with an RI
 constraint action of CASCADE, SET NULL, or SET DEFAULT must be journaled to the same journal

I've talked to the developer for the as400 and he said the file isn't journaled.

So I have tried a different approach. To insert using this method:

Exec ('Insert into mm410.inv801wk(edvend) values (21)') at s100405D.

It inserts two rows of data in the file and returns me:

Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

and it severs the database connection.

I have looked and tried just about everything I can think of. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is a connection string option to remove the requirement of a journal. Maybe that is the first approach to try. Since I am the .NET programmer AND the RPG programmer, I just journal the files I need to have journaled. But I know not everyone has that luxury.

Comment: We ended up having to use an odbc connection instead of a IBMDASQL. it worked just fine then.